# syntax error, unexpected 'layouts' (T_STRING), expecting ')' (View: C:\xampp7\htdocs\shopping\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

ican not open to page "register.blade.php" when I click to register itt alert this error
syntax error, unexpected 'layouts' (T_STRING), expecting ')' (View: C:\xampp7\htdocs\shopping\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php) I can open page login.blade.php 
my code in app.blade.php::

```
 <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
@if (Route::has('register'))
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
   </li>
@endif
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` in your `register.blade.php` file, can you post that file contents?

Comment: post file register.blade.php right?

Comment: Yes, post that file. There is an error in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your Register helper function, you are missing `')`

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
       {{ __('Register}}
 </button>
```

Change to

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
     {{ __('Register')}}
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

register.blade.php::

```js
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register}}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```